# Cannot plot my function : return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order) TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number

Tags: python, function, matplotlib, matrix, plot

I'm trying to plot a function that gives the arctan of the angle of several scatterplots (it's a physics experiment):

[image: scatterplot obtained by experimentation]

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

filename='rawPhaseDataf2f_17h_15m.dat'
datatype=np.dtype( [('Shotnumber',np.dtype('>f8')),('A1',np.dtype('>f8')),      ('A2',np.dtype('>f8')), ('f2f',np.dtype('>f8')), ('intensity',np.dtype('>f8'))])
data=np.fromfile(filename,dtype=datatype)

#time=data['Shotnumber']/9900 # reprate is 9900 Hz -> time in seconds
A1=data['A1']
A2=data['A2']

#np.sort()
i=range(1,209773) 

def x(i) :
    return arctan((A1.item(i)/A2.item(i))*(i/209772))
def y(i) : 
    return i*2*pi/209772

plot(x,y)

plt.figure('Scatterplot')
plt.plot(A1,A2,',') #Scatterplot
plt.xlabel('A1')
plt.ylabel('A2')

plt.figure('2D Histogram')
plt.hist2d(A1,A2,100) # 2D Histogram
plt.xlabel('A1')
plt.ylabel('A2')

plt.show()
```

My error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell   /sitecustomize.py", line 540, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "/home/nelly/Bureau/ Téléchargements/Kr4  Experiment/read_rawPhaseData.py", line 21, in <module>
    plot(x,y)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 2987, in plot
ret = ax.plot(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/axes.py", line 4138, in plot
self.add_line(line)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/axes.py", line 1497, in add_line
self._update_line_limits(line)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/axes.py", line 1508, in _update_line_limits
path = line.get_path()
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/lines.py", line 743, in get_path
    self.recache()
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/lines.py", line 420, in recache
    x = np.asarray(xconv, np.float_)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py", line 460, in asarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number
```

I know that the problem is from the `plot(x,y)`. I think that my error comes from the definition of `x` and `y`. `A1` and `A2` are matrix, `N` the number of points and `Ak` is the index of the matrix. I want to have `arctan(A1k/A2k)*(k/N)`.

Comment: What about a [mcve]?

Comment: So I don't know what you want to do here, but `x` and `y` are functions. You cannot provide a function to `plot`. Instead provide an array or a list to it.

Comment: OK so basically I need to create a list with all the points of my function ?

Comment: Seems like a reasonable thing to do, yes. Although as said, I do not know what you want to do and many things are undefined, e.g. it is unknown what `arctan` is and what you would feed into the functions as `i`.

Comment: Arctan is a fonction that should give me a plot with the shape of a potato ! But I should have a matrix with all the elements of my functions for this.. How can I generate a matrix like that ?  i is what I called k in the formula that I wrote (basically it's the index of the matrix A1 or A2)

Comment: I will stop here. If you are willing to provide a [mcve] and a clear problem description, one can look further into this.

Comment: Ok but it's about Carier-envelope phase measurement of few-cycle laser pulses. I'm not sure that it will help if I explain all the physics behind it. I just put my scatterplot in the first post. My problem is that I want the function that will define this plot and for this I know that I have to plot teta (x in the code) in function of psy (y in the code) that are definded by the formula that I used. I'm not a searcher so I cannot explain why is the polar angle the arctan of A1 and A2. I just know that I have to use this.

Comment: For the purpose of asking a question on SO, which is a Q&A site about programming it is completely irrelevant whether the data is coming from a CEP measurement or whether it depicts the locations of Yeti sightings. What matters is that the problem in terms of computer language is well defined. If there are unknown variables or functions in the code, one cannot help here.

Comment: Ok I understand. The problem is obviously that I'm not a programmer and I'm stuck with the informatic part. I don't know what is the best way to explain my problem in computer langage. Maybe can you tell me what is not clear ?
 My purpose is to get a plot of y in function of x. I just don't know how to do the plot because I defined x and y as functions. I suppose that I have to get the matrix of the elements given by the function.
Sorry English is not my mother langage so it's hard to speak clearly.

Comment: Start at the point where you have problems. Are you able to plot a sine wave in the range of 0 to 2pi? Can you relate your simple sine wave to what you are trying to do here? Depending on that you may also decide to postpone this task here and dive a bit deeper into python, numpy and matplotlib, looking at tutorials or examples.

Comment: OK thank you I will try to plot the sin wave and see if I can identify my problem. I'm also trying to read about python and matplotlib I haven't find the answer yet because I know how to do matrix with values that I know but not with the values given by a function

Comment: I'm saying this because `sin` is also a function. So there should not be much of a difference to `arctan` or any other function.

Comment: OK  I've done it with sin and now I can identitify my problem. The code for sin is that :    x = np.arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.01)
                          y = np.sin(2*np.pi*x)
                         plt.plot(x, y)
                         plt.show()                                                                         but here I don't have a function y(x) but I have x(A1k,A2k) and y(A1k,A2k) because x and y depends on the index of the matrix A1 and A2. So I want to have the entries of x in function of the entries of y. Is it comprehensible ?

Comment: Sorry I cannot write the code correctly on the comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of problems with your code, and your understanding of python and array operations.  I'm just going to handle the first part of the code (and the error you get), and hopefully you can continue to fix it from there.

This should fix the error you're getting and generate a plot:

```
# size = 209772
size = A1.size    # I'm assuming that the size of the array is 209772

z = np.arange(1, size+1)/(size+1)   # construct an array from [1/209773, 1.0]
# Calculate the x and y arrays
x = np.arctan((A1/A2)*z)
y = z*2*pi

# Plot x and y
plt.plot(x, y)
```

---

**Discussion:**

There are lots of issues with this chunk of code:

```
i=range(1,209773) 

def x(i) :
    return arctan((A1.item(i)/A2.item(i))*(i/209772))
def y(i) : 
    return i*2*pi/209772

plot(x, y)
```

1. You're defining two [functions](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Functions) called `x` and `y`, and then you are passing those *functions* to the plotting method.  The plotting method accepts numbers (in lists or arrays), not functions.  That is the reason for the error that you are getting.  So you instead need to construct a list/array of numbers and pass that to the function.
2. You're defining a variable `i` which is a list of numbers.  But when you define the functions `x` and `y`, you are creating *new variables* named `i` which have nothing to do with the list you created earlier.  This is because of [how "scope" works in python](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/learning-python/1565924649/ch04s03.html).
3. The functions `arctan` and `plot` are not defined "globally", instead they are only defined in the packages `numpy` and `matplotlib`.  So you need to call them *from* those packages.

Comment: Thank you now I understand better. The code that you gave me is working. It still don't give me what I look for but I think it's because of the physical part. Now I know how to do the code so I just have to modify the formula untill it works ! Thanks for your patience !

Comment: @Nelly no problem.  Don't forget to mark the answer as "Accepted" by clicking the green check-mark :)